# How to get data from the device using IOBufferMemoryDescriptor in driverKit

Tags: usb, ipados, driverkit

I'm trying to create a driver for my usb device, using iOS and DriverKit.

I'm basing my code in the example used in WWDC: https://github.com/knightsc/USBApp

My driver starts fine when the device is connected and the `readCompleted` method is called fine, but the `action->GetReference()` gets only `\0` characteres.

Also in order to know that the usb device is actually working I've connected it to my mac first and using `PyUSB` I can see that it's returning data in chunks of 1024 bytes in the interface 0.

This is the data I get in `PyUSB`:

```
array('B', [6, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 4, 0, 5, 0, 6, 0, 7, 0, 8, 0, 9, 0, 10, 0, 11, 0, 12, 0, 13, 0, 14, 0, 15, 0, 16, 0, 17, 0, 18, 0, 19, 0, 20, 0, 21, 0, 22, 0, 23, 0, 24, 0, 25, 0, 26, 0, 27, 0, 28, 0, 29, 0, 30, 0, 31, 0, 32, 0, 33, 0, 34, 0, 35, 0, 36, 0, 37, 0, 38, 0, 39, 0, 40, 0, 41, 0, 42, 0, 43, 0, 44, 0, 45, 0, 46, 0, 47, 0, 48, 0, 49, 0, 50, 0, 51, 0, 52, 0, 53, 0, 54, 0, 55, 0, 56, 0, 57, 0, 58, 0, 59, 0, 60, 0, 61, 0, 62, 0, 63, 0, 64, 0, 65, 0, 66, 0, 67, 0, 68, 0, 69, 0, 70, 0, 71, 0, 72, 0, 73, 0, 74, 0, 75, 0, 76, 0, 77, 0, 78, 0, 79, 0, 80, 0, 81, 0, 82, 0, 83, 0, 84, 0, 85, 0, 86, 0, 87, 0, 88, 0, 89, 0, 90, 0, 91, 0, 92, 0, 93, 0, 94, 0, 95, 0, 96, 0, 97, 0, 98, 0, 99, 0, 100, 0, 101, 0, 102, 0, 103, 0, 104, 0, 105, 0, 106, 0, 107, 0, 108, 0, 109, 0, 110, 0, 111, 0, 112, 0, 113, 0, 114, 0, 115, 0, 116, 0, 117, 0, 118, 0, 119, 0, 120, 0, 121, 0, 122, 0, 123, 0, 124, 0, 125, 0, 126, 0, 127, 0, 128, 0, 129, 0, 130, 0, 131, 0, 132, 0, 133, 0, 134, 0, 135, 0, 136, 0, 137, 0, 138, 0, 139, 0, 140, 0, 141, 0, 142, 0, 143, 0, 144, 0, 145, 0, 146, 0, 147, 0, 148, 0, 149, 0, 150, 0, 151, 0, 152, 0, 153, 0, 154, 0, 155, 0, 156, 0, 157, 0, 158, 0, 159, 0, 160, 0, 161, 0, 162, 0, 163, 0, 164, 0, 165, 0, 166, 0, 167, 0, 168, 0, 169, 0, 170, 0, 171, 0, 172, 0, 173, 0, 174, 0, 175, 0, 176, 0, 177, 0, 178, 0, 179, 0, 180, 0, 181, 0, 182, 0, 183, 0, 184, 0, 185, 0, 186, 0, 187, 0, 188, 0, 189, 0, 190, 0, 191, 0, 192, 0, 193, 0, 194, 0, 195, 0, 196, 0, 197, 0, 198, 0, 199, 0, 200, 0, 201, 0, 202, 0, 203, 0, 204, 0, 205, 0, 206, 0, 207, 0, 208, 0, 209, 0, 210, 0, 211, 0, 212, 0, 213, 0, 214, 0, 215, 0, 216, 0, 217, 0, 218, 0, 219, 0, 220, 0, 221, 0, 222, 0, 223, 0, 224, 0, 225, 0, 226, 0, 227, 0, 228, 0, 229, 0, 230, 0, 231, 0, 232, 0, 233, 0, 234, 0, 235, 0, 236, 0, 237, 0, 238, 0, 239, 0, 240, 0, 241, 0, 242, 0, 243, 0, 244, 0, 245, 0, 246, 0, 247, 0, 248, 0, 249, 0, 250, 0, 251, 0, 252, 0, 253, 0, 254, 0, 255, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

This is the `Ivars`:

```
struct Mk1dDriver_IVars
{
    IOUSBHostInterface       *interface;
    IOUSBHostPipe            *inPipe;
    OSAction                 *ioCompleteCallback;
    IOBufferMemoryDescriptor *inData;
    uint16_t                  maxPacketSize;
};
```

This is the `Start` method:

```
kern_return_t
IMPL(Mk1dDriver, Start)
{
    kern_return_t                    ret;
    IOUSBStandardEndpointDescriptors descriptors;
    
    ret = Start(provider, SUPERDISPATCH);
    __Require(kIOReturnSuccess == ret, Exit);
    
    ret = RegisterService();
    if (ret != kIOReturnSuccess)
    {
        Log("Start() - Failed to register service with error: 0x%08x.", ret);
        goto Exit;
    }
    
    ivars->interface = OSDynamicCast(IOUSBHostInterface, provider);
    __Require_Action(NULL != ivars->interface, Exit, ret = kIOReturnNoDevice);
    
    ret = ivars->interface->Open(this, 0, NULL);
    __Require(kIOReturnSuccess == ret, Exit);
    
    ret = ivars->interface->CopyPipe(kMyEndpointAddress, &ivars->inPipe);
    __Require(kIOReturnSuccess == ret, Exit);
    
    ret = ivars->interface->CreateIOBuffer(kIOMemoryDirectionIn,
                                           1024,
                                           &ivars->inData);
    
    __Require(kIOReturnSuccess == ret, Exit);
    
    ret = OSAction::Create(this,
                           Mk1dDriver_ReadComplete_ID,
                           IOUSBHostPipe_CompleteAsyncIO_ID,
                           0,
                           &ivars->ioCompleteCallback);
    
    __Require(kIOReturnSuccess == ret, Exit);
    
    ret = ivars->inPipe->AsyncIO(ivars->inData,
                                 ivars->maxPacketSize,
                                 ivars->ioCompleteCallback,
                                 0);
    __Require(kIOReturnSuccess == ret, Exit);
    
    os_log(OS_LOG_DEFAULT,"Finish");

    // WWDC slides don't show the full function
    // i.e. this is still unfinished
    
Exit:
    return ret;
}
```

The only difference in this compared with the code from Apple is that I set `capacity` in the method `CreateIOBuffer` to 1024. This is because if I leave it to `0` it will return an error that memory could not be allocated: `kIOReturnNoMemory`

And the `ReadComplete` method:

```
void
IMPL(Mk1dDriver, ReadComplete)
{
    
    char output[1024];
    memcpy(action->GetReference(), &output, 1024);

    os_log(OS_LOG_DEFAULT,"ReadComplete");
```

If I put a breakpoint in the log, I can see all the positions in `output` will be `\0`

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to store some reference to the `IOBufferMemoryDescriptor*` that you asked `AsyncIO` to write to when the data from the device is received (`ivars->inData`) so that you can access it when the completion callback `ReadComplete` is called. You can store this in the memory that you can access with `GetReference()`.

You should set the size of the custom memory that should be allocated for you. Currently you are allocating 0 bytes. See [OSAction::Create](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/kernel/osaction/3438206-create).

In `ReadComplete` you can then call `GetReference()` to access the memory. Since you know that this memory contains a reference to the `IOBufferMemoryDescriptor` that data has been written to, you can then use it with `memcpy`.

Something like this:

```
ret = OSAction::Create(this,
                       Mk1dDriver_ReadComplete_ID,
                       IOUSBHostPipe_CompleteAsyncIO_ID,
                       sizeof(IOBufferMemoryDescriptor*),
                       &ivars->ioCompleteCallback);

memcpy(ivars->ioCompleteCallback->GetReference(),
       ivars->inData, sizeof(IOBufferMemoryDescriptor*));
```

First parameter to `memcpy` is the destination.

```
void IMPL(Mk1dDriver, ReadComplete)
{    
    IOBufferMemoryDescriptor* ptr;
    memcpy(ptr, action->GetReference(), sizeof(IOBufferMemoryDescriptor*));
    IOAddressSegment addressSegement{};
    ptr->GetAddressRange(&addressSegement);

    char output[1024];
    memcpy(output, addressSegement.address, addressSegement.length);
}
```